# If i change my disks in a ReadyNAS 1100 - will I lose the data?

Tags: network-attached-storage, readynas, raid

I have a ReadyNAS 1100, with 4X1.5TB disks.

Due to some problems, I am thinking to do the following:

- Take the 4 HD's out (4X1.5TB identical disks, keep the order)
- Put new 4 Disks in (4X500GB identical disks, smaller disks - still identical)
- Restore to factory default
- Once NAS is working properly take the 4 disks out
- Put the original 4X1.5TB disks in the correct order.

Do you think I will loose the data?  (P.S. please do not refer me to ReadyNAS forums - been there, done that - no help)

I think that the procedure will work as I don't think that the controller stores the hardware data in itself, but rather in the disks.

Comment: 15 TB disks? Are you from the future?

Comment: 1.5 TB (typo edit)

Comment: What's the point of this exercise?

Comment: As Chris pointed out: i want to restore to factory default, without loosing my data

Comment: How about you backup your data first?

Comment: I can't access the required data. Only option is to image the disks and than try to mess with them, but that still doesn't solve my hardware issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you already [got your answer](http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=55764&p=316055#p316058). I will agree with the prevailing wisdom here - contact ReadyNAS support. They're likely going to be the only ones that can give you a definitive answer here.

Comment: As you can see, ReadyNAS were contacted 12 days ago. No answer yet. I am still waiting. I thought the question is a general one. If I take a set of disks, and replace with a different set, nothing should happen to the data. That's what I am asking.

Comment: @Saariko - there's very little "general" information available about proprietary RAID solutions. My gut feeling is that your data *should* be there after swapping the disks, but you had better make sure that you have a good backup before doing this.